# How to remove postfix from a string in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, substring

I want to to this in shell-script: remove the file postfix and save it into another variable:

```
file=abcabc.cpp
postf=.cpp
name=${file##postf}
echo $name
```

But this couldn't work. I want name=abcabc after the operation. Can you help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use:

```
name="${file%$postf}"
echo "$name"
abcabc
```